# How do I further remove this background?

Tags: gimp, transparency, background-removal

So, I have removed the background of the logo for my site, but the background of my site is a dark grey. As a result, the logo has a white border around it that looks messy. I use GIMP for editing and I'm not sure how I could remove the outline without spending hours removing each pixel. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to create some shapes outside problematic area and changes the stroke/fill to background:

Outside -

[image]

Inside -

[image]

Result (1 min work) -

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks amazing. Would you charge to complete it? Thanks.

Comment: works nice for the logo, but how would you do the type?

Comment: @Vincent The type is for whatthefont and replacement of course...

Comment: @HarryK What do you mean charge? We don't look for clients here :) - try to identify the font and replace it... i.e. recreate the whole logo yourself :))

Comment: How do you create that outside shape like in that 1st image and what did you do right after that - you filled it?

Comment: @Amphiteót This is Pen tool, NO-FILL, Stroke converted from red to background black

Comment: @Ilan Thank you for the cue! I don't have experience with the software and the keyboard shortcuts etc. I'll practice!

Answer (score 0):

Try a combination of adding a inner stroke of 1-2 px, inner glow of 1-2 px and a inner shadow that's 1-2 px. All dark. This will make the inner edges of your logo dark - hence mix itself better with the background. This is a fix that works with your dark background.

If you need it for another colored background - make the effects in the same color. To make the logo workable for all kinds of backgrounds you must edit its edges better, and it may still not be smooth.